# The attachable property 'Triggers' was not found in type 'FontImageSource'

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am trying to have conditional usage linked to the FontImageSource of an ImageButton but am running into issues with using DataTriggers.

Below is my code, I am receiving this error when compiling:

The attachable property 'Triggers' was not found in type 'FontImageSource'.

```
<ImageButton
            Padding="0"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            HorizontalOptions="End">
            <ImageButton.Source>
                <FontImageSource FontFamily="FontAwesome6Solid"
                        Color="LightGray"
                        Glyph="{x:Static fontAwesome:FontAwesomeIcons.Check}">
                    <FontImageSource.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger TargetType="FontImageSource"
                                        Binding="{Binding HasDelivered, Source={x:Reference bubble_fdasdl}}"
                                        Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Color" Value="MediumAquamarine"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger TargetType="FontImageSource"
                                        Binding="{Binding HasBeenRead, Source={x:Reference bubble_fdasdl}}"
                                        Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Glyph" Value="{x:Static fontAwesome:FontAwesomeIcons.CheckDouble}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </FontImageSource.Triggers>
                </FontImageSource>
            </ImageButton.Source>
        </ImageButton>
```

Comment: You can only attach Triggers to a `View`. `ImageButton` is a view, aka a control. You can trigger on `ImageButton.Source` being set to a value. Or you can set `ImageButton.Source` to a new value. BUT `FontImageSource` is NOT a view. Can't put a Trigger on it. AFAIK, a trigger can't be used to manipulate properties of FontImageSource.

Answer (score 1):

As @ToolmakerSteve said, you cannot change `FontImageSource`'s properties with a `Trigger`. Instead, you can change the entire `ImageSource` with a trigger on the `ImageButton` like so:

```xml
<ImageButton
    Padding="0"
    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
    HorizontalOptions="End">

    <ImageButton.Source>
        <FontImageSource
            FontFamily="FontAwesome6Solid"
            Glyph="{x:Static fontAwesome:FontAwesomeIcons.Check}"
            Color="LightGray" />
    </ImageButton.Source>

    <ImageButton.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger
            Binding="{Binding HasDelivered, Source={x:Reference bubble_fdasdl}}"
            TargetType="ImageButton"
            Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Source">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <FontImageSource
                        FontFamily="FontAwesome6Solid"
                        Glyph="{x:Static fontAwesome:FontAwesomeIcons.Check}"
                        Color="MediumAquamarine" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger
            Binding="{Binding HasBeenRead, Source={x:Reference bubble_fdasdl}}"
            TargetType="ImageButton"
            Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Source">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <FontImageSource FontFamily="FontAwesome6Solid" Glyph="{x:Static fontAwesome:FontAwesomeIcons.CheckDouble}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </ImageButton.Triggers>

</ImageButton>
```